# Update an application give the error "Application not installed" in android 6+

Tags: android

I released a widget and everything worked fine but I recently updated that project to an app and widget, in android devices below 6 it gets successfully updated but in android 6+ it does not update. I should first uninstall the privious version and then install new version. can anyone guess what is my problem?
the package names are the same.

Comment: May you are trying to install unsigned app when an signed app is installed

Comment: did you add any new dependencies into the gradle after the previous update

Comment: @Rasel , No it is signed app, as I told in question it android below 6 it updates successfully

Comment: did you change targetSdkVersion ?

Comment: Are you using v1 and v2 for signing apks?

Comment: @Naz141, it is related to not update in android 6+? because it successfully installed but it does not update

Comment: @Sanoop, it does not have the option v1 and v2 in android studio 2.2

Comment: I had the same issue when the final .apk was signed with different certificates.

Comment: @Serg_, you mean it got updated in some devices and not update to others?

Comment: Yes, it may be the reason.

Comment: @Serg_,actually they are the same :(